# How do i get every second word in a string including the first one?

Tags: python

Define a function called print_skip that accepts a string and prints out every second word in the string, starting with the first word.  A word is treated as any sequence of letters that is separated from other letters by white space.  You may assume a string is passed as a parameter.

thats the problem i'm having.

i tried to put it in a a list and index it from there and it works fine and passed most of the test that the website gives except one.

print_skip('Hello    world!\nHow\nare\nyou!') and the excepted output is Hello How you. my code just crash when this happens

```
def print_skip(text):
only_letters = ''
new_words = []
for c in text:
    if(c.isalpha() or c==' '):
        only_letters += c
for x in only_letters.split():
    new_words.append(x)
for i in range(0,len(new_words)+1,2):
    print(new_words[i])
```

[testing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kGRp.png)

[my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO58w.png)

[this is the original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykpm3.png)

Comment: please post code as text in the question, links die eventually

Comment: Just so you know, you can add code blocks in SO by indenting them 4 spaces, or pressing `ctrl+K`

Comment: oh cool cool let me have a play around with it :) thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 4):

So strings in python actually let you index them like a list.  Here's an example:

```
>>> myString = "How are You?  Where are you from?"

>>> breakUp = myString.split()

>>> breakUp[::2] #This 2 represents step size, so ever 2nd word will be called. 


['How', 'You?', 'are', 'from?']
```

Notice this includes the first word.

Appendum:  So just using the split() here is not enough.  I looked at the above example and the escape characters are in the string.  I think a viable solution to dealing with escape characters inside your string are just replacting them with a ''.  Here is an example:

```
myFixedString = "'Hello world!\nHow\nare\nyou!".replace('\n', ' ')
printSkip(myFixedString)
```

Comment: Your explanation is a little misleading.  `myString.split()` returns a list, so you never actually index into the string directly.

Comment: `str.split` will split newlines just fine, you don't need to replace them.

Comment: so in regards to my code. It works fine. I just dnt know how to get to pass the last test?

Comment: This is a great time to inject a trace ;)  pdb ftw.

Comment: @RockAndRoleCoder what does that mean? haha btw i'm a beginner coder :(

Comment: so pdb is a great tool for debugging your code.  Its much faster if you just youtube: "How to use python pdb module"

Comment: ahh right i mean... i kind of know where the problem is.. I just dont know how to fix it? if that makes  any sense. I just dont know how to get to the output i needed. I thought i got it right but nope :(

Comment: Ok can you update your question with more code ?  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @RockAndRoleCoder the code that i have posted is my own. The question is asking to modify the code so i did that and yeah thats where I am at, and you can see the test below

Comment: Ok think I have your issue, give me couple of min to figure it out.

Comment: Ok so your last half of the string is reading as a single word: 'Hello world!\nHow\nare\nyou --> ['Hello', '\nHow\nare\nyou'].  I have go eat, but if you don't have an answer by then I'll take another look this evening.

Comment: @RockAndRoleCoder thank you for helping and i will be moving on as i got 6 other more questions :) and ill come back to it :) spent so much time on it haha if youhave the solution do let mek now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solution using for loop and modulo:

```
sentence = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n8 9 10'
words = sentence.split()
for i in range(len(words)):
    if i % 2 == 1:            # is true on uneven numbers, e.g. index 1, index 3, index 5
        print(words[i])

>>>2
>>>4
>>>6
>>>8
>>>10
```

This can be refactored down to a list comprehension as follow:

```
sentence = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n8 9 10'
words = sentence.split()
[print(words[i]) if i % 2 == 1 else None for i in range(len(words))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex and `re.sub` to remove all non-alphabetic characters for each odd word in the string.

```
import re

def print_skip(text):
    if not text:
        return
    regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
    for index, word in enumerate(text.split()):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            print(regex.sub('', word))
```

Method without using regex:

```
def print_skip(text):
    words = text.split()
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if not word.isalpha():
            clean_word = ''
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if word[i].isalpha():
                    clean_word += word[i]
            words[index] = clean_word
        if index % 2 == 0:
            print(words[index])
```

Comment: Now I'm jealous, stil haven't cracked the re code myself.  Keep meaning to get back there.

Comment: I've added a method without using regex, still follows the same logic but manually removes any non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: this looks good but i dont know how to change it to make it look different so i dont get hit by pledgerism